# jQuery Tricky thing, Top slider change to slide from the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

[image: The main Question printed on the picture]

Okey My is Web design on Photoshop and The other programmer or coders make it alive. I've been thinking that why not that i can do it myself. So it's my first project and jQuery is not my thing though. So i'm asking you guys some help. Please do help me :D

The jquery

```
/*
 * jQuery Color Animations
 * Copyright 2007 John Resig
 * Released under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 */

(function(jQuery){

    // We override the animation for all of these color styles
    jQuery.each(['backgroundColor', 'borderBottomColor', 'borderLeftColor', 'borderRightColor', 'borderTopColor', 'color', 'outlineColor'], function(i,attr){
        jQuery.fx.step[attr] = function(fx){
            if ( fx.state == 0 ) {
                fx.start = getColor( fx.elem, attr );
                fx.end = getRGB( fx.end );
            }

            fx.elem.style[attr] = "rgb(" + [
                Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[0] - fx.start[0])) + fx.start[0]), 255), 0),
                Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[1] - fx.start[1])) + fx.start[1]), 255), 0),
                Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[2] - fx.start[2])) + fx.start[2]), 255), 0)
            ].join(",") + ")";
        }
    });

    // Color Conversion functions from highlightFade
    // By Blair Mitchelmore
    // http://jquery.offput.ca/highlightFade/

    // Parse strings looking for color tuples [255,255,255]
    function getRGB(color) {
        var result;

        // Check if we're already dealing with an array of colors
        if ( color && color.constructor == Array && color.length == 3 )
            return color;

        // Look for rgb(num,num,num)
        if (result = /rgb\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*\)/.exec(color))
            return [parseInt(result[1]), parseInt(result[2]), parseInt(result[3])];

        // Look for rgb(num%,num%,num%)
        if (result = /rgb\(\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*\)/.exec(color))
            return [parseFloat(result[1])*2.55, parseFloat(result[2])*2.55, parseFloat(result[3])*2.55];

        // Look for #a0b1c2
        if (result = /#([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/.exec(color))
            return [parseInt(result[1],16), parseInt(result[2],16), parseInt(result[3],16)];

        // Look for #fff
        if (result = /#([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])/.exec(color))
            return [parseInt(result[1]+result[1],16), parseInt(result[2]+result[2],16), parseInt(result[3]+result[3],16)];

        // Otherwise, we're most likely dealing with a named color
        return colors[jQuery.trim(color).toLowerCase()];
    }

    function getColor(elem, attr) {
        var color;

        do {
            color = jQuery.curCSS(elem, attr);

            // Keep going until we find an element that has color, or we hit the body
            if ( color != '' && color != 'transparent' || jQuery.nodeName(elem, "body") )
                break; 

            attr = "backgroundColor";
        } while ( elem = elem.parentNode );

        return getRGB(color);
    };

    // Some named colors to work with
    // From Interface by Stefan Petre
    // http://interface.eyecon.ro/

    var colors = {
        aqua:[0,255,255],
        azure:[240,255,255],
        beige:[245,245,220],
        black:[0,0,0],
        blue:[0,0,255],
        brown:[165,42,42],
        cyan:[0,255,255],
        darkblue:[0,0,139],
        darkcyan:[0,139,139],
        darkgrey:[169,169,169],
        darkgreen:[0,100,0],
        darkkhaki:[189,183,107],
        darkmagenta:[139,0,139],
        darkolivegreen:[85,107,47],
        darkorange:[255,140,0],
        darkorchid:[153,50,204],
        darkred:[139,0,0],
        darksalmon:[233,150,122],
        darkviolet:[148,0,211],
        fuchsia:[255,0,255],
        gold:[255,215,0],
        green:[0,128,0],
        indigo:[75,0,130],
        khaki:[240,230,140],
        lightblue:[173,216,230],
        lightcyan:[224,255,255],
        lightgreen:[144,238,144],
        lightgrey:[211,211,211],
        lightpink:[255,182,193],
        lightyellow:[255,255,224],
        lime:[0,255,0],
        magenta:[255,0,255],
        maroon:[128,0,0],
        navy:[0,0,128],
        olive:[128,128,0],
        orange:[255,165,0],
        pink:[255,192,203],
        purple:[128,0,128],
        violet:[128,0,128],
        red:[255,0,0],
        silver:[192,192,192],
        white:[255,255,255],
        yellow:[255,255,0]
    };

})(jQuery);
```

The html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/temp.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Nofu entertainment</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
<div id="panel">
    <!-- you can put content here -->
</div>
<p class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide">Slide Panel</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 570px;
    font: 75%/120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
#main {
    margin: 100px 0;
    width: 570px;
    height: 570px;
}
#panel {
    background: #754c24;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
}
.slide {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: solid 4px #422410;
    background: url(../images/btn-slide.gif) no-repeat center top;
}
.btn-slide {
    background: url(../images/white-arrow.gif) no-repeat right -50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 144px;
    height: 31px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    font: bold 120%/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.active {
    background-position: right 12px;
}
```

Comment: So no one know how to do it? or just?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/5c49W/1/)

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div rel="1" class="box">1</div>
  <div rel="2" class="box">2</div>
  <div rel="3" class="box">3</div>
  <div rel="4" class="box">4</div>
  <div rel="5" class="box">5</div>
  <div rel="6" class="box">6</div>
 </div>
 <div class="slidepanel">
  <div class="closebtn">X</div>
  <div class="content"></div>
 </div>​
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width:400px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:100px;
}
.box{
    width:70px;
    height:45px;
    background:orange;
    float:right;
    margin:20px;
    border-radius:7px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:25px;
}
.slidepanel{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    background:brown;
    width:0px;
    height:300px;
}
.closebtn{

    color:white;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:red;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.content{
    font-size:60px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:50px;
}
​
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
  $('.slidepanel').animate({"width":"500px"},1000);
  var i=$(this).attr('rel');
  $(".content").html(i);
});
$('.closebtn').click(function(){
  $('.slidepanel').animate({"width":"0px"},1000);
});
```

​